# Problems reloading data in a tableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, reloaddata

I am trying to reload data in a tableview based on a users account permissions whenever they log in.

The two classes involved in this are:

*mainViewController* and *menuViewController*

Currently I am able to use

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

To reload the data when called within the *viewWillAppear* method. Which is no good for me since the user hasn't logged in when the view loads so there is no data to populate the table at this point.

I have created a method called *populateTable* in menuViewController.h which I am calling in the mainViewController.m file on button press using the following;

```
(IBAction)Reload:(id)sender { 
menuViewController *mvc = [[menuViewController alloc]init];
[mvc populateTable];
}
```

This seems to work correctly as I have an NSLog within the populateTable method which executes. However the reloadData does not work.

Here is my populateTable method;

```
-(void)populateTable {
self.section1 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"test settings", @"test",           @"test",@"Users and access",@"No-track IPs", nil];
self.section2 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Rules",     @"Channels",@"Goals",@"Pages", nil];
self.menu = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:self.section1, self.section2, nil];
[self.tableView reloadData];
NSLog(@"Reloading data");
}
```

Can you guys help me out here, I have been staring at this all day and getting nowhere, thanks!

Comment: So your tableview is in the menuViewController ?

Comment: At what point is menuViewController's view added to the view heirarchy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience this is likely a problem with timing - the `IBOutlet` of `self.tableView` is not ready when you call reloadData on it (add an `NSLog` and see for yourself - it is `nil` when called).

To solve this, the populateTable method must be called within the UIViewController's `viewDidLoad` method. This guarantees that the outlets are not nil and that everything is ready for your data population.

Also, you should not instantiate your `MenuViewController` with `[[MenuViewController alloc] init]` but using the storyboard's `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`.

Comment: Sorted my problem, I was being stupid, i changed menuViewController *mvc = [[menuViewController alloc]init]; to  menuViewController *mvc = (menuViewController*) self.slidingViewController.underLeftViewController;

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is this line,

```
menuViewController *mvc = [[menuViewController alloc]init];
```

This creates a new instance of menuViewController, not the one you see on screen. You need to get a reference to the one you have, not create a new one. How you get that reference depends on how, when, and where your controllers are created.